how to update old react project to be able to use a new node module
I need to implement a new npm that uses hooks and providers. The project I need to include this in is pre hook react (16.4.x). Would it be best to upgrade to 16.8.0 (version to introduce hooks) or just use the latest version. From my understanding, all old react code should still work, including class components.
Also, I'm not sure if I need to also update other node modules due to the update to React using hooks, such as the react-router, react-router-dom, redux etc If these need to be updated to be compatible with React 16.8+, how can I find which version it was?

Updating from 16.4.x to the latest ^16 - which is 16.14.0 - is non breaking and should be completely painless. It's extremely unlikely you're 16.4.x project will work on 16.8, but not on 16.14.0.
Upgrading to 17 may cause some issues with the loss of event pooling. You may be lucky and be unaffected, the only way to know for sure is to test your project out after upgrading.
I'd start by upgrading to the latest 16 and then upgrade further if you need/want to, seeing how the dependency you're trying to install just needs something greater than 16.8
